# Get event logs and count warnings

Tags: powershell

```
(Get-EventLog -LogName System | Where-Object {$_.EntryType -eq "Warning"}).count
```

If I run the command, it returns all warnings, but I only want to extract the count for only 4 event IDs for example 1006,1007,455 and 6003. Could someone help me in this case?

Comment: `(Get-EventLog -LogName System -InstanceId 1006,1007,455,6003 -EntryType 'Warning').count`. When in doubt a good read on the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1) is likely to answer your question.

Comment: take a look at `get-help Get-WinEvent -Parameter FilterXPath` for ways to get ONLY the event ids that you want.

Answer (score 3):

Get-Event with FilterHashtable does the job:

```
(Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ logname = 'System'; Level = 3; Id = 1006,1007,455,6003 }).count
```

Level values:

```
Comment(or Verbose)  5
Information          4
Warning              3    [int][System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.StandardEventLevel]::Warning
Error                2
Critical             1
LogAlways            0
```

or create an object

```
 $Event = @{
 Warning = [int][System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.StandardEventLevel]::Warning
 Error = [int][System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.StandardEventLevel]::Error
 }
```

`$Event.Warning` gives the value 3

Comment: It's also worth noting that this is a lot more efficient than retrieving *all* events first and filtering them down with `Where-Object`.

Comment: I tried to set level with an enum but it's awkward.  `[int][System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.StandardEventLevel]'warning'`

Comment: use [int][System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.StandardEventLevel]::Warning

Comment: I guess in an ideal world the type of the level would be an array of StandardEventLevel's, and you could just say 'warning' and have it convert to int, but that's not the case.

Comment: create an object Event with key "warning" and value [int][System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.StandardEventLevel]::Warning, and you could call $Event.Warning, see my answer modifed

Comment: why have you opened another (same) question?  close this by validating an answer , its very confuse to have 2 similary questions

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command to get the result you want:

```
 (Get-EventLog -LogName System | Where-Object {$_.EntryType -eq "Warning"} | Where-Object {$_.InstanceId -like "1006" -or $_.InstanceId -like "1007" -or $_.InstanceId -like "455"} -or $_.InstanceId -like "6033"}).count
```

The result to will get the count of InstanceId's you provided.

Option 2 - If you want to find count for records from last 2 hours then use below command:

```
 (Get-EventLog -LogName System -After (Get-Date).AddHours(-2) | Where-Object {$_.EntryType -eq "Warning"} | Where-Object {$_.InstanceId -like "1006" -or $_.InstanceId -like "1007" -or $_.InstanceId -like "455"} -or $_.InstanceId -like "6033"}).count
```

Comment: Hii, ((Get-EventLog -LogName System -InstanceId 1006,1007,455,6003 -EntryType 'Warning').count)- This command is running but i want this event id count for last 2 hours how shall i modify this  could someone help in this case?

Comment: Hi I have edited the command. Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Hii, Thanks i have already tried this code.i got ouput for this. But for this path (Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName="Microsoft-Windows-AAD/Operational";Level = 3;StartTime=(get-date).AddHours(-2); Id=1097})-iam not able to get the output. i want the count for this path(Microsoft-Windows-AAD/Operational).

Comment: This is the following errors i have got(Get-EventLog : The event log 'Microsoft-Windows-AAD/Operational' on computer '.' does not exist.
At line:1 char:2
+ (Get-EventLog -LogName Microsoft-Windows-AAD/Operational | Where-Obje ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-EventLog], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetEventLogCommand)could someone help in this case?

Comment: (Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName="Microsoft-Windows-AAD/Operational";Level = 3;StartTime=(get-date).AddHours(-2); Id=1097}).count

5

This command is working in my system. Please try running powershell as admin.